# How do you build an Android back stack when an activity is started directly from a notification?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have two activities:

Activity A - list of items
Activity B - detail view of an item

Normally, a user opens the app and Activity A is launched.  A user sees a list of items, clicks one, and Activity B is started to display the item detail.

Activity B can also be started directly from clicking on a notification.  In this case there is no back stack.

How can I make it so that when Activity B is started directly from a notification, the user can click the Back button and go to Activity A?

Comment: I never being to this situation,so my answer might not be perfect. Instead of starting Activity B...Start Activity A and pass a value using Intent from your receiver and check for that value in onCreate of Activity A, if condition satisfies start Activity B. So through this you will have Activity A in backStack. But only catch is that user will see weird animation like Activity A coming and transitioning to Activity B. Does this make sense ?

Comment: @gopal yes I was considering implementing something like that.  I will try it soon and report back.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add an Extra into the Intent launched by the notification to detect when the app has been launched in that way.

Then you can override the `onBackPressed()` Activity method and handle that scenario, e.g.

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed()
  {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    boolean launchedFromNotif = false;

    if (extras.containsKey("EXTRA_LAUNCHED_BY_NOTIFICATION"))
    {
      launchedFromNotif = extras.getBoolean("EXTRA_LAUNCHED_BY_NOTIFICATION");
    }

    if (launchedFromNotif)
    {
      // Launched from notification, handle as special case
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
      mActivity.startActivity(intent);
      finish();
    }
    else
    {
      super.onBackPressed();
    }    
  }
```

Comment: 1up because this solution is api-level independent, contrary to the PendingIntent.getActivities() solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13801159/1894568)

Comment: A check whether the `extras` bundle is not `null` is needed before accessing it.

Comment: @AndacAydin What do you mean by "PendingIntent.getActivities() is API-level dependent" ? As Cassio Landim points out, I'd recommend the "TaskStackBuilder" solution, editing the backStack, as advised by the guidelines.

Answer (score 10):

You should take care of this when you receive the Notification.

I have a similar situation solved:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context,ListDetail.class);
 TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
 stackBuilder.addParentStack(ListDetail.class);
 stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
 PendingIntent contentIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 NotificationManager mNotifM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
 mNotifM.notify(NotificationId.getID(), mBuilder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle(mBuilder)
            .bigText(bigText)
            .setBigContentTitle(title)
            .setSummaryText(summaryText))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentText(summaryText)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setTicker(bigText)
            .build());
```

You need to set in your Manifest the hierarchy of the Activities:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ListDetail"
        android:label="Detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".List" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".List" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tried one sample.Please go through with this link

```
https://github.com/rajajawahar/NotificationBackStack
```

> Activity you want to launch..

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class).putExtra("Id", id);
```

> Parent Activity, if back pressed

```
Intent parentIntent = new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
```

> Add Both the activity in the taskbuilder

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context); 
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(parentIntent).addNextIntent(launchIntent).getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, notificationCompatBuilder.build());
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationCompatBuilder.setAutoCancel(true).
                setContentTitle("First Notification").
                setContentText("Sample Text").
                setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(id, notificationCompatBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

catch the back-button-key event with onKeyDown()-method and let the user go to activity A. Don't forget to return true to prevent the event from being propagated further.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

Comment: By "let the user go to Activity A", do you mean create an Intent and start Activity A?  If I did that, and the user pushed the back button in Activity A, they would go back to Activity B, right?

Comment: yes, that's right. If you want to prevent this behaviour, try finishing your activity B after starting Activity A, i.e.: 
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();