# Return to Main Activity after TAG_DISCOVER

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nfc

I finally got my app reacting to TAG. Its build from 2 different activities.
activity A is the Main activity, that get launched when i start the app.
And then there is activity B which is being launched by a TAG_DISCOVER.
However i have 2 problems now.

(1)
Activity B has a backButton, which just does finish(); If the app were manually started i would just return to activity A, as its being startet first. However if activity B is directly launched through a discovered TAG, A isnt launched, so when pushing the BackButton the App exits, which i dont want.

(2)
Each time I discover a TAG Activity B gets launched, eventhough it might already exist. But I want Activity B to only be active once a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113766/how-do-you-build-an-android-back-stack-when-an-activity-is-started-directly-from)

You should be able to use the same approach - detect that the activity was launched from a Tag and go 'back' to the main activity.